# Как максимально оптимизировать и улучшить код (RDP)? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, rdp

И так, хотел сделать маленький RDP (без манипуляторов) с клиентом и сервером. Есть небольшой код на создание, сжатие, отправку и прием изображений. Вроде бы все хорошо все работает, но даже на локалке идут дикие артефакты (при том что половину изображения принимается нормально), через сеть ещё не пробовал, думаю будет также.

[image: Артефакты на localhost] 
У меня недостаточно знания чтобы максимально оптимизировать этот код, по этому прошу вашей помощи!

**Код: Отправляющий SendStream.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client.Sender
{
    public class SendStream
    {
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private UdpClient _udpClient;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private const UInt16 UdpSize = 65507;
        private const UInt16 ControlBlockSize = 5;
        private Random random = new Random();
        private byte lastA = 0; // Последний код цепочки
        private byte lastB = 0; // Последний код цепочки
        private float FPS = 60;

        public SendStream()
        {
            // Загружаем номер порта, на которой надо встать
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("ip.txt"))
            {
                string ip = streamReader.ReadLine();
                int port = Convert.ToInt32(streamReader.ReadLine());

                if (ip != null) ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            }

            width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        }

        public async Task Run()
        {
            _udpClient = new UdpClient();
            Bitmap backGround = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(backGround);

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay((int) (1000 / FPS));
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height)); // Получаем снимок экрана

                byte[] bytes = ConvertToByte(backGround); // Получаем изображение в виде массива байтов
                List<byte[]> data = Package(bytes); // Упаковка изображения в протокол

                foreach (var block in data)
                {
                    await _udpClient.SendAsync(block, block.Length, ipEndPoint);
                }
            }
        }

        /* 
         * Конвертируем изображение в массив байтов со сжатием
         * Jpeg - качество средние, скорость средние, потери малые (полупрозрачные, 40-60%)
         * Gif - качество плохое, скорость максимальное, потери огромные (тв, 90%)
         * Png - качество выше-среднего, скорость выше-среднего, потери средние (серый цвет, 40-60%)
         *
        */
        private byte[] ConvertToByte(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }


        // Пакеты для передачи UDP
        private List<byte[]> Package(byte[] bt)
        {
            int countMsg = (int) Math.Ceiling(bt.Length / (double) UdpSize); // Количество сообщений
            List<byte[]> chain = new List<byte[]>(); // Цепочка сообщений

            if (countMsg > 65536)
                throw new Exception(
                    "Вы пытаетесь передать сообщение больше 4 ГБ - протокол не подерживает передачу свыше 4 ГБ");

            byte[] controlBlock = new byte[ControlBlockSize]; // Формируем контрольный блок
            controlBlock[0] = 1;

            byte a, b;
            do
            {
                a = (byte) random.Next(0, 256);
                b = (byte) random.Next(0, 256);
            } while (a == lastA && b == lastB);
            // Цикл нужен, чтобы случайно не совпал код сообщений из другой цепочки, 
            // в одной из параллельных вселенной этот цикл выполняется бесконечно

            controlBlock[1] = a;
            controlBlock[2] = b;
            controlBlock[3] = BitConverter.GetBytes(countMsg)[0];
            controlBlock[4] = BitConverter.GetBytes(countMsg)[1];

            chain.Add(controlBlock);

            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < countMsg; i++)
            {
                byte[] msgBlock = new byte[UdpSize]; // Формируем блок сообщения
                msgBlock[0] = 0;
                msgBlock[1] = a;
                msgBlock[2] = b;

                msgBlock[3] = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)[0];
                msgBlock[4] = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)[1];

                int msgBlockLength;
                if (bt.Length - offset <= UdpSize)
                {
                    msgBlockLength = bt.Length - offset;
                }
                else
                {
                    msgBlockLength = UdpSize - 7; // 5 - в данном случае первые 5 байтов
                }

                msgBlock[5] = BitConverter.GetBytes(msgBlockLength)[0];
                msgBlock[6] = BitConverter.GetBytes(msgBlockLength)[1];

                if (i == countMsg - 1)
                {
                    Array.Copy(bt, offset, msgBlock, 7, bt.Length - offset);
                }
                else
                {
                    Array.Copy(bt, offset, msgBlock, 7, UdpSize - 7);
                }

                chain.Add(msgBlock);

                offset += UdpSize;
                if (offset > bt.Length)
                {
                    offset = bt.Length;
                }
            }

            return chain;
        }

        /*  Описание протокола передачи LO поверх UDP
            1 байт - контрольный пакет (1 если контрольный и 0 если не контрольный)

            Расположение байтов для контрольного пакета
            2 - 3 байт кодовый номер цепочки пакетов
            4 - 5 байт количество пакетов

            Расположение байтов для неконтрольного пакета
            2 - 3 байт кодовый номер пакета
            4 - 5 байт номер пакета
            5 - 6 байт размер пакета, а именно данных без первых 6 байт (включая нулевой байт).
         */
    }
}
```

**Код: Принимающий TakeStream.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace Server.Receiving
{
    class TakeStream
    {
        private int TTL = 70; // Время жизни пакетов
        private List<Packet> turn = new List<Packet>(); // Очередь сообщений
        private List<Packet> controls = new List<Packet>(); // Контрольные пакеты

        public delegate void EventReady(BitmapImage img);

        public event EventReady FrameReady;

        private struct Packet
        {
            public bool isControl; // Это контрольный пакет?
            public UInt16 id; // ID цепочки
            public byte[] date; // Данные пакета
            public UInt16 count; // Количество пакетов
            public UInt16 number; // Порядковый номер пакета
            public int TTL; // Длительность жызни пакета или контрола
        }

        public TakeStream()
        {
        }

        public void addPacked(byte[] data)
        {
            Packet packet = decodeMsg(data);

            if (packet.isControl)
            {
                controls.Add(packet);
            }
            else
            {
                turn.Add(packet);

                for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (controls[i].id == packet.id && controls[i].count - 1 == packet.number)
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Compare(packet.id));

                        controls.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;

                        BitmapImage bitmapImg = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmapImg.BeginInit();
                        bitmapImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        bitmapImg.StreamSource = ms;
                        bitmapImg.EndInit();
                        bitmapImg.Freeze();

                        FrameReady(bitmapImg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Сообщение
        private Packet decodeMsg(byte[] data)
        {
            Packet packet = new Packet();
            packet.TTL = 0;
            packet.isControl = data[0] == 1;
            packet.id = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 1);

            if (packet.isControl)
            {
                packet.count = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                packet.number = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 3);
                packet.date = new byte[BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 5)];

                try
                {
                    Array.Copy(data, 7, packet.date, 0, packet.date.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }

            return packet;
        }

        // Исходные данные
        private byte[] Compare(UInt16 id)
        {
            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < turn.Count; i++)
            {
                if (turn[i].id == id)
                {
                    data.AddRange(turn[i].date);
                    turn.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }

            return data.ToArray();
        }

        private void RemoveChain(UInt16 id)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < turn.Count; i++)
            {
                if (turn[i].id == id)
                {
                    turn.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        /*  Описание протокола передачи LO поверх UDP
            1 байт - контрольный пакет (1 если контрольный и 0 если не контрольный)

            Расположение байтов для контрольного пакета
            2 - 3 байт кодовый номер цепочки пакетов
            4 - 5 байт количество пакетов

            Расположение байтов для неконтрольного пакета
            2 - 3 байт кодовый номер пакета
            4 - 5 байт номер пакета
            5 - 6 байт размер пакета, а именно данных без первых 6 байт (включая нулевой байт).
         */
    }
}
```

**Код: Принимающий UserControlScreenStream.cs** 
P.S. форма пустая с заданным размером

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using PRP_Server.Receiving;

namespace Server.UserControls
{
    public partial class UserControlScreenStream : UserControl
    {
        private UdpClient udpClient;
        private const UInt16 UdpSize = 65507;
        private const UInt16 ControlBlockSize = 5;

        private delegate void AsynkWorker();

        private delegate void DrawEvent(BitmapImage bitmapImage);

        private delegate void Invoke(byte[] data);

        private TakeStream takeStream = new TakeStream();
        private UInt16 _port;

        public UserControlScreenStream()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            takeStream.FrameReady += new TakeStream.EventReady(decoder_FrameReady);
            new AsynkWorker(Run).BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        void decoder_FrameReady(BitmapImage img)
        {
            this.Background = new ImageBrush(img);
        }

        void MainWindow_Invoke(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                takeStream.addPacked(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("port.txt"))
            {
                _port = UInt16.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            }

            UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port));
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.None, 0);

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] mass = udp.Receive(ref ep);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Invoke(MainWindow_Invoke), mass);
            }

            /* byte[] test = new byte[5];
            test[0] = 1;
            test[1] = 2;
            test[2] = 3;
            test[3] = 4;
            test[4] = 5;

            decoder.addPacked(test); */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/142617/ :-)

Comment: @DigitalCore есть немного)

Comment: Вы взяли чужой код, не разобрались в нем, и просите доработать. Никто не будет доделывать работу вместо вас. Если бы код писали вы сами, то сами нашли проблему, и задали короткий и понятный вопрос.

Comment: Судя по картинке, у вас просто бесконечная рекурсия идет, окно отображает скриншот самого себя и так далее пока все не ломается. Да и FPS слишком высокий, 60 кадров в секунду вряд ли получится обеспечить выбранными средствами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо оптимизировать код, особенно чужой, не так уж просто. Для этого есть несколько популярных методов.

1. «Метод пристального взгляда».

   Вы внимательно читаете код и пытаетесь угадать, где же в нём наиболее часто выполняющийся кусок, или кусок, который создаёт наибольшую нагрузку на память/процессор/и. т. п. В этом куске имеет смысл подумать, можно ли его как-нибудь улучшить. Например, накопление строки в цикле имеет смысл заменять на использование `StringBuilder`. Возможно, кое-где в критических по производительности частях программы придётся отказаться от использования мощных средств наподобие LINQ. После каждого проведённого изменения обязательно перепроверяйте, является ли оно реально оптимизацией, или, наоборот, лишь ухудшает дело.

   Не старайтесь улучшить *всю* программу, это отнимет у вас слишком много времени и не окупится вообще никак. Избегайте ухудшения читаемости программы.

   Недостаток этого метода в том, что даже опытные программисты не всегда могут «на глазок» установить реальную причину просадки производительности, и много времени зачастую тратится на бессмысленные не-оптимизации наподобие «переиспользовать переменную цикла» или «развернуть LINQ в процедурный код после ввода с клавиатуры».
2. Алгоритмические оптимизации и выбор структур данных.

   Нередко производительность фрагмента программы можно улучшить в разы, выбрав подходящие алгоритмы и/или структуры данных. Очень часто в качестве универсальной структуры данных используется `List<T>`, в котором поиск и добавление может быть *очень* медленным. Имеет смысл задать себе вопрос: какие операции с моей структурой данных нужны, и как часто они будут выполняться? В зависимости от этого нужно подбирать подходящую структуру данных.

   Аналогично предыдущему случаю, после каждого проведённого изменения обязательно перепроверяйте, улучшает ли это реально ситуацию.

   Недостаток этого метода — он не всегда применим, т. к. в простых программах может и не быть алгоритмических проблем.
3. Профилирование.

   Зачем гадать, где проблема, если можно просто измерить? Запуская программу с профайлером, вы видите, в каких местах происходит реальная задержка. Оптимизируя именно этот код (ускоряя выполнение или просто переструктурировав программу так, чтобы медленный код вызывался реже), вы добьётесь хорошего прироста производительности с достаточно небольшими изменениями. Профайлер позволит не пытаться проводить бессмысленные оптимизации кусков, которые в оптимизации не нуждаются.

   Недостаток этого метода — необходимо научиться читать и понимать вывод профайлера. Профайлер не подскажет волшебным образом, какую именно строку в исходниках нужно изменить, он лишь покажет, что на самом деле происходит медленно. Ещё один недостаток, если вы программист-любитель — хорошие профайлеры стоят денег. Если же вы занимаетесь коммерческим программированием, обязательно приобретите профайлер, без него никуда.

Comment: Профилировщика встроенного в студию недостаточно?

Comment: [Руководство по профилированию производительности для начинающих](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182372.aspx)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Даже не знаю, я использую Ants.